# select fields and group them in a category in php and mysql

Tags: php, mysql

i have a table with staff_id and subjects, i want to display all staffs according to their subjects.

**my table**
[image]

**result i want**

```
Physics
  -001
  -004
  -006
Chemistry
  -002
  -009
Biology
  -003
  -008
Mathematics
  -005
```

**My code**

```
 $q = mysql_query("Select staff_id from my_table");
   while($row = mysql_fetch_array($q)){
      echo $subject .'</br>';

      echo $staff_id.'</br>';

    }
```

but this doesn't give the result i want.
any help?

Comment: Please dont use `mysql_*` functions anymore cause they're deprecated. Use `PDO` or `mysqli_*` instead.

Comment: `GROUP BY` will help you a little

Comment: ok, i will move to mysqli_*, thanks for advise @TiMESPLiNTER

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

```
$q = mysql_query("SELECT `staff_id`, `subject` FROM `my_table`;");
$data = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($q)){
    $data[$row['subject']][] = '-'.$row['staff_id'];
}
print_r($data);
```

Or to echo out the rows

```
foreach($data as $heading => $rows){
    echo $heading.'<br>';
    foreach($rows as $row){
        echo $row.'<br>';
    }
}
```

Comment: this seems to work but there is one field i want to add to this array, how can i do it.?

Answer (score 2):

What you need is `ORDER BY`.

Change your query to:

```
SELECT STAFF_ID, SUBJECT FROM my_table ORDER BY SUBJECT, STAFF_ID
```

So you get the records in the right order to work with them.

Answer (score 0):

```
    $result=mysql_query("SELECT * from table GROUP BY subject");

    while($ext=mysql_fetch_object($result)) {
        $query=mysql_query(" SELECT * from table WHERE subject='".$ext->subject."'");
        echo $ext->subject;

        while($res=mysql_fetch_object($query)) {
            echo $res->staff_id;
        }    
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write your code like this below:

```
$q = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM my_table ORDER BY SUBJECT, STAFF_ID");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($q)){
 //Do staff
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code should help. You should split each subject into a separate array within your query. Once your query is complete, you should iterate through the subject array, and then within each staff id.

```
$subjects = array();
$q = mysql_query("Select staff_id from my_table");
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($q)){
        if ($subjects[$row['SUBJECT']] == nil) {
            $subjects[$row['SUBJECT']] = array();
        }
        array_push($subjects[$row['SUBJECT']], $row['STAFF_ID']);
    }
foreach ($subjects as $key=>$value) {
    echo $key . '<br>;
    foreach ($vaue as &$staff) {
        echo $staff . '<br>';
    }
}
```